# Parsing a Path containing Ampersand in a windows BAT

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using this script from another source to convert files from .ts to .mp4:

```
set i=%~n1
set x=%~x1
set o=%i%.mp4
if exist %o% (
  set o=%i%-h264.mp4
)
ffmpeg -i "%i%%x%" -map -0:v? -c copy "%o%"
pause
```

Only issue is it fails if the source name contains a `&`. I've tried wrapping various bits in additional `""` but no luck. Any help would be great

Comment: Try doublequoting all of your command lines! i.e. ```set "i=%~n1"```, ```set "x=%~x1"```, ```set "o=%i%.mp4"```, ```if exist "%o%" (set "o=%i%-h264.mp4")```. Although that whole thing could be done in a single commandline, ```@if exist "%~n1.mp4" ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -map -0:v? -c copy "%~n1-h264.mp4"```

Comment: "fails" - what does it do that you don't expect? What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: @Compo that got it! I'll give your slicker code a whirl too. Cheers